# Average of M2M element in ListView

Tags: python, django

This is my model:

```
class FruitItem(models.Model):
    vote = models.IntegerField()

class Fruit(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=77)
   items = models.ManyToManyField(FruitItem)
```

This is my views:

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class FruitsList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'fruits.html'
    context_object_name = "fruits"
    paginate_by = "8"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Fruit.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(
                            vote_avg=Avg('items__vote'))
```

and template:

```
{% for f in fruits %}
    {{ f.name }}
    {{ f.items.vote_AVERAGE }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I display `vote` average for every list element?(`{{ f.items.vote}}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Avg

def get_queryset(self):
    return Fruit.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(
                                vote_avg=Avg('items__vote'))
```

Now each Fruit object in the template context has a `vote_avg` attribute containing the average of the related FruitItem.vote fields.

Comment: @user3355631 Error where? Please post the actual traceback.

Comment: I can't replicate that, I'm afraid: the code given works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry. My fault. It works for `Avg`. Not working for `Sum` - `Fruit.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).aggregate(Sum('items__vote'))`

Comment: Because you're using aggregate, not annotate. Aggregate returns a single object which is the value over the whole queryset. Annotate adds a value for each item in the queryset, which is what ListView (in particular, the pagination) is expecting.

Comment: You wouldn't use a ListView for that, since you would only have a single value, not a list.